# "Anthony Gray" app runs in background. Where is it? What is it?

Tags: macos, ventura, activity-monitor

I have an app called "Anthony Gray" with permissions to run in Background.
[image: Allow in the Background apps]

But it's not present with this name in the Applications folder or htop.

Is there another way to know where it is or what it is?

Comment: Check the names of the developers of the programs you have installed especially recently. Sometimes a program appears in the "Allow in the Background" part of the system settings under a name different from the program's.

Comment: @Alper is correct.  This is however, a good example of the need to slow down and carefully reading the security pop-up dialogs that macOS generates.  This app could never have been granted this permission without you authorizing it by entering your credentials (password, touchID)

Comment: I didn't installed anything from individual developers recently. The last updates I had here are VPN, Telegram, Firefox and Slack. I can't find anything related to this app or this developer.

Comment: I googled "developer Anthony Gray Mac", which gave me an Apple Discussion page with "com.mac.adg.SquidMan.plist (Anthony Gray)"

Comment: You just solved the mistery. In fact I have been using Squidman for months, even in my previous macbook, but never noticed this background item. Thanks for clarifying that. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anthony "Tony" Gray is the developer of [SquidMan](https://squidman.net/squidman/), which is some sort of internet proxy server.

It installs a Privileged Helper Tool.